# Do we need $\mu, \nu$ to be $\sigma$-finite to show $\int fg \ d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int f \ d\mu \int g \ d\nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, products

The problem statement:

> Let $(X, \mathcal F, \mu), (Y, \mathcal G, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite and $f \in \mathcal L^1 (\mu), g \in \mathcal L^1 (\nu)$. Show that $fg \in \mathcal L^1 (\mu \otimes \nu)$ and $$\int fg \ d(\mu \otimes \nu) = \int f \ d\mu \int g \ d\nu.$$

I did the usual routine: let first $f,g$ be indicator functions, then simple functions, then non-negative measurable, then integrable.

My question is: where does one (implicitly) use the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu, \nu$? I went throw the argument and couldn't spot the place. Since this was a stand-alone exercise, I though it's rather unlikely for the setup to be redundant.

Comment: $\mu\otimes\nu$ is only well-defined when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: This is not true as stated. You probably mean something like $f \otimes g$ instead of $fg$, where $(f\otimes g)(x,y) = f(x) g(y)$. For the rest, see the comment of Stefan Hansen. More precisely, one usually defines $\mu \otimes \nu$ to be the unique measure with $(\mu \otimes \nu)(A\times B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$. Uniqueness may fail if the factors are not sigma finite, so that the product measure is not well defined in that case.

Comment: @StefanHansen: would you mind writing it as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu \otimes \nu$ is only well-defined when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite. –  [Stefan Hansen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/25632/stefan-hansen)

Comment: There are various definitions of product measures out there, and some can be applied to arbitrary measure spaces. See the discussion in Fremlins treatise on measure theory in chapter  25.